# Canvas mouse move

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, mousemove

Maybe you can help me, i need to create an animation with jquery and canvas. So, i would like to change the color of my canvas element when mouse move, the color rgb must be random and change when the mousemove change.

This is my code (canvas + query) :

```
window.onload = function()
{
    var canvas  = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');

      function drawanim(color){

      context.fillStyle=color;
      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(106,20);
      context.lineTo(130,67);
      context.lineTo(182,74);
      context.lineTo(144,111);
      context.lineTo(153,163);
      context.lineTo(106,139);
      context.lineTo(60,163);
      context.lineTo(69,111);
      context.lineTo(31,74);
      context.lineTo(83,67);
      context.lineTo(106,20);
      context.fill();
    }
    drawanim("color");

// SOURIS POSITION
      var $canvas = $('#canvas'),
      w = 0,h = 0,
      rgb = [],
      getWidth = function() {
          w = $win.width();
          h = $win.height();
      };
    $('#canvas').resize(getWidth).mousemove(function (e) {
        rgb = [
              Math.round(e.pageX/w * 255),
              Math.round(e.pageY/h * 255),
              150
          ];

          drawanim("rgb('+rgb.join(',')+')");
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not building the string correctly:

```
  drawanim("rgb(" + rgb.join(",") + ")");
```

One way to tell is to note how the syntax detector on this site colors the code. In your case, it colored the entire expression as a single string.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the RGB to be truly random:

```
rgb = [
    0 | Math.random() * 256,
    0 | Math.random() * 256,
    0 | Math.random() * 256
];

drawanim("rgb(" + rgb.join(",") + ")");
```

Or, as your code poses, for it to respond to cursor position; what you have should work, you just need to correct the quotes here:

```
drawanim("rgb(" + rgb.join(",") + ")");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it's work !! Sorry i'm a beginner and i learn a lot thanks to all !!